# How to make a valid test using the mockito library?

Tags: junit, mockito

**The context**
I have a simple method that I'm testing using the mockito library.

**The problem**
I have a error:

"[MockitoHint] ReceiveServiceTest.testGetFileDto (see javadoc for MockitoHint):
[MockitoHint] 1. Unused... -> at .ReceiveServiceTest.testGetFileDto(ReceiveServiceTest.java:46)
[MockitoHint]  ...args ok? -> at ReceiveService.getFileDto(ReceiveService.java:28)

I dont understand way.

**The code**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ReceiveServiceTest {
private List<File> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();

@InjectMocks
private ReceiveService receiveService;

@Mock
private FindFiles findfiles;

@Mock
private ReadByte readByte;



@Before
public void before() {
    filePaths.add(new File("d://folder//test1_message_received"));
    filePaths.add(new File("d://folder//test2_message_received"));
    filePaths.add(new File("d://folder//test3_message_received"));
}

@Test
public void testGetFileDto() throws IOException {

    // Given
    byte[] resultByteArr = new byte[1028];
    when(findfiles.getPathFiles()).thenReturn(filePaths);
    when(readByte.readByteArrFromFile(new File("d://folder//test3_message_received"))).thenReturn(resultByteArr);

    List<MessageDTO> result = receiveService.getFileDto();
    //some assert
    }
```

**method**

```
@Autowired
private FindFiles findFiles;

@Autowired
private ReadByte readByte;

public List<MessageDTO> getFileDto() throws IOException {
    List<MessageDTO> fileDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File file : findFiles.getPathFiles()) {
        fileDtos.add(new MessageDTO(Base64.getEncoder().encode(readByte.readByteArrFromFile(new File(file.getPath()))),
                file.getName(), "zip", null));
    }
    return fileDtos;
}
```

Comment: Don't use absolute file paths in your application / tests. Always use relative paths / resource loading and add the files used in tests also to your SCM repository.

Comment: Use better names for your interfaces / implementations:
FindFiles -> FileFinder -> or more specific, for example ScenarioFileFinder
ReadByte -> ByteReader

Answer (score 0):

I think mocks are not being initialized. Please initialize the mocks in the `@Before` method.

```
@Before
public void init() {
    initMocks(this);
}
```

This should solve the problem I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you create a new object in the following line:

```
when(readByte.readByteArrFromFile(new File("d://folder//test3_message_received"))).thenReturn(resultByteArr);
```

Mockito needs to know which real object is passed to the method so that it can return the appropriate `thenReturn`-value. So if you pass the actual reference into it, your code will work, but also only if you specify all the values which are listed. Otherwise you may get a `NullPointerException`.

By the way, calling `new File(file.getPath())` seems redundant to me. You can just use `file` instead.

So with the following your code might work better:

```
when(readByte.readByteArrFromFile(filePaths.get(0)).thenReturn(resultByteArray);
```

but then you need to specify it for all entries.

Alternatively, use a `Matcher` instead:

```
when(readByte.readByteArrFromFile(ArgumentMatchers.any(File.class))).thenReturn(resultByteArr);
```

or specify the actual argument matching you require as matchers can be very powerful in that regard.

**Previously the answer contained the following, which is still true, but not as concise as the answer above:**

It's been a long time since I last used mocks (and I am even proud of it ;-)).

The message already states that one should consult the [javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/quality/MockitoHint.html) and there I found the following:

> Those are hints - they not necessarily indicate real problems 100% of the time.

Nonetheless, I believe the problem is with the following statement:

```
when(readByte.readByteArrFromFile(new File("d://folder//test3_message_received"))).thenReturn(resultByteArr);
```

I think *you need to specify a return for every entry in the `filePaths`* or make the call more generic using `Matchers.any()` (or any other appropriate `Matcher`).

Comment: Can you please add the corresponding line numbers (28&46) as code comment in your question? Just to be sure that also others look at the right line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for my problem. I added foreach loop. Now the mock works, but byte [] is different than what it should return.

```
// Given
    byte[] mockByteArr = new byte [2048];
    when(findfiles.getPathFiles()).thenReturn(filePaths);
    for (File filePath : filePaths) {
        when(readByte.readByteArrFromFile(new File(filePath.getPath()))).thenReturn(mockByteArr);
    }
    //When
    List<MessageDTO> result = receiveService.getFileDto();
    //Then
    assertEquals(3, result.size());
    assertEquals(mockByteArr, result.get(1).getContent());
```

Comment: If my answer in any way gave you a hint, e.g. "I think you need to specify a return for every entry", then feel free to upvote it. By the way I just downloaded mockito again and updated my answer to explain why your initial approach did not work. Regarding your next problem, please update your question or ask a new one (depending on what's more appropriate). This could also be reflected with an edit comment in your question.

Comment: What does `getContent()` return?